# Can't determine why program terminates early

Tags: python, edx

I was working on this assignment for the EdX MIT Python course and decided I wanted the output to display differently.  Based on my code, I thought that the task program would end when guesses = 0.  However, I'm either getting "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" or the program ends at guess 2.  This appears to depend on the length of the secretWord.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
def hangman(secretWord):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the secret word to guess.

    Starts up an interactive game of Hangman.

    * At the start of the game, let the user know how many 
      letters the secretWord contains.

    * Ask the user to supply one guess (i.e. letter) per round.

    * The user should receive feedback immediately after each guess 
      about whether their guess appears in the computers word.

    * After each round, you should also display to the user the 
      partially guessed word so far, as well as letters that the 
      user has not yet guessed.

    Follows the other limitations detailed in the problem write-up.
    '''
    trackedguess = []
    letcount = ()
    letterlist = []
    guess = ''
    for i in range(0, (len(secretWord)-1)):
        trackedguess.append('_')
    letcount = len(secretWord)
    guessesleft = 8

    for i in range(0, 7):
        if ''.join(trackedguess) == secretWord:
            print('You win!')
            break
        if guessesleft < 1:
            print('You have 0 guesses remaining.')
            break
        print(trackedguess)
        print("You have ", guessesleft, " guesses remaining.")
        guess = input('Please guess a letter and press return:  ')
        if guess in letterlist:
            print("You've already guessed that.  Try again.")
        else:
            guessesleft -= 1
            letterlist.append(guess)
            for i in range(0, len(secretWord)):
                if secretWord[i] in letterlist:
                    coordinate = i
                    trackedguess[coordinate] = secretWord[i]


hangman(chooseWord(wordlist))
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things stick out to me:

1. `range` uses an *exclusive* end.  That means `range(0, (len(secretWord)-1)` will iterate one time *less* than the length of `secretWord`.  You want the lengths to match.  More straightforward, less error-prone approaches would be just: `trackedGuess = ['_'] * len(secretWord)` or `trackedGuess = list('_' * len(secretWord))`.
2. You should verify your assumptions.  For example, the above case could have been caught easily if you did `assert(len(trackedGuess) == len(secretWord))`.
3. `for i in range(0, 7)` suffers from the same problem as your earlier usage of `range()`.  If you want to iterate 8 (`guessesleft`) times, then you should use `range(0, 8)`.  However, you're also decrementing `guessesleft` inside the loop and exiting when it reaches 0.  Do one or the other, but not both.  As your code currently is, if someone enters a guess that they've already made, it will count one iteration against them (which I'm not sure is what you want).

Comment: Thank you!  It's really useful to see how others approach this kind of problem.  After awhile of working on it it's like I can only see what's in front of me.

Comment: I should really build in checks for my code, as you stated, that would have caught the problem earlier.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very good attempt, but there are some things that are wrong. I'm going to try to walk through them one by one.

Instead of a `for` loop, I'd suggest using a `while guessesleft>0`. In the current implementation the for loop will run for 8 times regardless of whether or not there are any guesses left (for example, try providing the same letter as a guess every time). With the `while`, however, you gain much more control over the loop.

The `trackedguess` generation is flawed. It will always miss the last letter of the `secretword` (this is also the reason you were getting the `IndexError`) Try `for i in range(len(secretWord))` instead. You'll also find it much more concise and readable.

I also took the liberty of moving the win or lose condition down in the loop. Previously, if you won on the last guess, you'd still lose (because the win check condition happened before the input and after that the loop ended); also, the guess wasn't printed if you won (because the loop would break before the print statement).

Revised code below:

```
def hangman(secretWord):
'''
secretWord: string, the secret word to guess.

Starts up an interactive game of Hangman.

* At the start of the game, let the user know how many
  letters the secretWord contains.

* Ask the user to supply one guess (i.e. letter) per round.

* The user should receive feedback immediately after each guess
  about whether their guess appears in the computers word.

* After each round, you should also display to the user the
  partially guessed word so far, as well as letters that the
  user has not yet guessed.

Follows the other limitations detailed in the problem write-up.
'''
trackedguess = []
letterlist = []
for i in range(len(secretWord)):
    trackedguess.append('_')
guessesleft = 8

while guessesleft > 0:
    print(trackedguess)
    print("You have ", guessesleft, " guesses remaining.")
    guess = input('Please guess a letter and press return:  ')
    if guess in letterlist:
        print("You've already guessed that.  Try again.")
    else:
        guessesleft -= 1
        letterlist.append(guess)
        for i in range(0, len(secretWord)):
            if secretWord[i] in letterlist:
                coordinate = i
                trackedguess[coordinate] = secretWord[i]
    if ''.join(trackedguess) == secretWord:
        print(trackedguess)
        print('You win!')
        break
    if guessesleft < 1:
        print('You have 0 guesses remaining.')
        break


hangman('test')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you!  It really helps to see the the mistakes I was making and actually see the program functioning correctly.